# How to Stop a For Loop when a value is found from a .csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a Network Engineer trying to learn programming using Python. I'm very new to any form of programming.

I'm trying to search for a value in column 1 from a .csv file and return the string of corresponding column. When the program is executed, it loops through all the cells, displaying the result of each cell. What I want is if a user enters a number, then it needs to search the list, once a match is found, return the next column's string. If a user entered a value that doesn't exist then return a print statement.

```
import csv
import sys

fileName = 'sip.csv'
READ = 'r'
WRITE = 'w'

enter_code = input('Enter The Sip Response Code: ')
with open(fileName, READ) as myXLfile:
    dataFromFile = csv.reader(myXLfile)
    for currentRow in dataFromFile:
        if enter_code == currentRow[0]:
            print("The SIP Response Code you entered is: " + enter_code)
            print("The SIP Message is:  " + currentRow[1])
            print("Meaning:  " + currentRow[2])
            break
        if enter_code != currentRow[0]:
            print("Im Sorry, I Do not have this Response Code")
    else:
        print("Thank You and Goodbye")
```

Result:

```
Enter The Sip Response Code: 200
Im Sorry, I Do not have this Response Code
Im Sorry, I Do not have this Response Code
Im Sorry, I Do not have this Response Code
Im Sorry, I Do not have this Response Code
Im Sorry, I Do not have this Response Code
Im Sorry, I Do not have this Response Code
The SIP Response Code you entered is: 200
The SIP Message is:  OK
Meaning:  The request has been successfully processed and the result of the request is transmitted in the response.
```

Comment: Your question is not fully clear, a sample of `sip.csv` would help.  What is the desired output vs the output you get for some sample `sip.csv` file?

Comment: Hi Dillon. What error or incorrect result are you getting when you run your code?

Comment: @Hoog, Thanks for coming back to me. Basically I have a table of a +/- 2000 Lines of data in a .csv format. I want a User to search a value anywhere in the first column and return the information from the next row. If a match is found the code needs to stop looping. If no match found, then print a message, However,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean like this:

```
import csv

fileName = 'sip.csv'
READ = 'r'
WRITE = 'w'
check = True

enter_code = input('Enter The Sip Response Code: ')
with open(fileName, READ) as myXLfile:
    dataFromFile = csv.reader(myXLfile, delimiter=";")
    for currentRow in dataFromFile:
        if enter_code == currentRow[0]:
            print("The SIP Response Code you entered is: " + enter_code)
            print("The SIP Message is:  " + currentRow[1])
            print("Meaning:  " + currentRow[2])
            check = False
            break
    if check:
        print("Im Sorry, I Do not have this Response Code")
    else:
        print("Thank You and Goodbye")
```

Comment: @bart cubrich, Thanks for responding. Your suggestion worked. I did not had to add the delimiter=";" statement. It works exactly as I want it to. Thanks so much. Now unto the next phase of this task, trying to use tkinter and make a gui for this.

Comment: Dillon please consider marking @The_C0der's answer as accepted (check mark on the left) since it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @glhr. very new to this world:)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you.

```
# Select All From CSV File Where

import csv
# Asks for search criteria from user
search_parts = input("Enter search criteria:\n").split(",")
# Opens csv data file
file = csv.reader(open("C:\\your_path\\test.csv"))
# Go over each row and print it if it contains user input.
for row in file:
    if all([x in row for x in search_parts]):
        print(row)
```